# In react-native error while doing npm install gettng below

Tags: react-native, npm

Today i want to install this [lib](https://github.com/hrutvikpatel/react-native-character-input).

But unfortunately I got the following error.

> npm ERR! code ERESOLVE npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency
> tree npm ERR! npm ERR! While resolving: my-app@1.0.0 npm ERR! Found:
> react@17.0.1 npm ERR! node_modules/react npm ERR!   react@"17.0.1"
> from the root project npm ERR! npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
> npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.1" from react-native-character-input@1.0.5
> npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-character-input npm ERR!
> react-native-character-input@"*" from the root project npm ERR! npm
> ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry npm ERR! this
> command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps npm ERR! to accept an
> incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

What does this mean that the version of the my react-native is incompatible with this lib?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have **dependency conflict** (*incorrect and potentially broken dependency*) as it says, so try to run the command with `--force`, or `--legacy-peer-deps`. If it doesn't take effect, the **temporary solution** is using prior versions of the Node.js (downgrading the Node.js version) as it causes this kind of errors to happen sometimes.

Comment: Thank you it works! But it means that this lib will not work correctly ?

Comment: It will work, in simple words it's like there is a clash between two library's that use a common parent library, so you force install it, and remove the extra installed parent library.

Answer (score 2):

try
`npm install --legacy-peer-deps react-native-character-input --save`